# Extracting images from excel sheet by row with python

Tags: python, excel, image

I am trying to extract images from excel sheet. The excel sheet is basically a list of products with images and details of products.

with

```
EmbeddedFiles = zipfile.ZipFile(path).namelist()
ImageFiles = [F for F in EmbeddedFiles if F.count('.jpg') or F.count('.jpeg')]
```

I can extract all images at once but i cannot figure out a way to get images by row so that i could save products into database and add images to respective products.

I was using openpyxl to read from excel but that does not provide a way to get images. I can shift to other libraries.

What would be the best way to do this.

Comment: From what I can see here you are opening a `zip` file and you are listing all its contents that are images. How does that excel file fit into the picture? Are the images in a zip file or encoded in a excel file?

Comment: xlsx are actually zipped and when you unzip an xlsx file, you get a folder with images in it

Answer (score 0):

The `xlsx` file is indeed in compressed format, but that does not mean that you have to expand it to work with it. Let `openpyxl` do that for you. The library in its documentation mentions that it can handle this format pretty well.

So try opening the file and reading line by line using [this](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/tutorial.html#loading-from-a-file), [this](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells) and [this](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook) example found in the documentation

Comment: this i am already doing. with openpyxl i can iterate rows and lets say print values but it is not doing anything about the images in the sheet.

Comment: The image is contained in a cell as a base64 encoded string? Each image should belong to a cell, open the xlsx file and click on the image to see in which cell does it belong.