Extracting images from an excel file row by row using openpyxl
I am working on a project, and first I need to extract some data from an excel file. This data include images (.png). I tries various python scripts from online websites and AI, but none of them seems to be working.
from openpyxl import load_workbook,drawing
import os

def extract_images_from_excel(excel_file_path, output_folder):
    # Load the workbook
    wb = load_workbook(excel_file_path, data_only=True)

    # Iterate through all sheets in the workbook
    for sheet_name in wb.sheetnames:
        sheet = wb[sheet_name]

        # Iterate through all cells in the sheet
        for row in sheet.iter_rows():
            for cell in row:
                # Check if the cell contains an image
                if isinstance(cell.value, drawing.image.Image):
                    image = cell.value
                    image_path = os.path.join(output_folder, f"{sheet_name}_image_{cell.coordinate}.png")
                    image.save(image_path)
                    print(f"Image saved: {image_path}")

    # Close the workbook
    wb.close()

# File paths
excel_file_path = r"C:/Users/A/Downloads/x/Me.xlsx"
output_folder = r"C:/Users/A/Downloads/x/output_images"

# Extract images
extract_images_from_excel(excel_file_path, output_folder)


This is the code I used, however it produced no output at all. I also tried this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430039/extracting-images-from-excel-sheet-by-row-with-python" but the links inside it are outdated.
The new code extracts the images, but it fails to store images of each row separateltly
import zipfile
import os

def extract_images_from_excel(excel_file_path, output_folder):
    # Create the output folder if it doesn't exist
    os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)
    
    # Extract images from the xl/media directory
    with zipfile.ZipFile(excel_file_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(output_folder)
        
    print("Images extracted.")

# File paths
excel_file_path = r"C:/Users/AUC/Downloads/x/MedDigi-G.xlsx"
output_folder = r"C:/Users/AUC/Downloads/x/output_images"

# Extract images
extract_images_from_excel(excel_file_path, output_folder)


if isinstance(cell.value, drawing.image.Image): ??? A cell.value is not ever going to be a drawing.image.Image so the code wont ever pass that line. Unzip the XLSX file and get the images from the '...\xl\media' directory is the recommendation from Openpyxl. But otherwise there are examples to do this, see this answer on finding images in an Excel Sheet.

I tried the code from the link, but it did not work, however unzipping the xlsx file worked. The problem is I want the images of each row to be stored separately. Is there a way to modify the new code (I will provide it above) to do this.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

maybe use print( type(cell.value) ) to see what types it can have. And later use these information to fix script.
